# Removing the label lines appearing on d3 donut chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

am actually trying to remove the part of the label lines that appear on donut arc,ie want lies to begin outside the donut chart.
Code am using is

```
var outerArc = d3.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)
            .innerRadius(radius * 0.9);

function midAngle(d) { return d.startAngle + ((d.endAngle - d.startAngle)) / 2; }
  if (lablesettings.show) {

        var enteringLabels = svg.selectAll(".polyline").data(pie(viewModel.dataPoints)).enter();
        var labelGroups = enteringLabels.append("g")
                                        .attr("class", "polyline")
                                        .style("fill", "none")
                                        .style("stroke", "grey")
                                        .style("stroke-width", "1px")
                                        .style("opacity", "0.4");

        var line = labelGroups.append("polyline").attr('points', function (d) {
            var arccentroid = arc.centroid(d);
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
            pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
           //var fpos=((arccentroid[0]+pos[0])/2 (arccentroid[1]+pos[1])/2);
           return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos
        });
```

Please suggest me the modifications by which i can land at my requirement.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Simplistic solution? Simply draw the labels and lines first, then the pie on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. The points array stops right where it starts getting interesting. Could you post the rest of that statement?

From what I see so far, I'd say to remove the `arc.centroid(d)` from the `points` array.